# Display large array in laravel blade in too much time

Tags: laravel, time, view, laravel-blade, execution-time

so i got imported my large excel file with huge informations with 1 sec and i did get all the information i need to display within 1 sec to , but i got a big probleme when displaying the array in the view coz i m testing if the cells are correct or not i m using 5 ifs and 3 foreach and it takes mote than 2 mins , i need help to display all the info in a short time this is my array , and thanks
[image]

[image]

and there is my code of the view which takes to much time to display infos
[image]

and thanks

```
//here we get our final result of true and false fields
    $finale_array = [];
   
    // here we get all our 
    $current_table2 = [];
    $results_applied = [];
    $current_result = [];
    $columns = SCHEMA::getColumnListing('imports');

    // here we get all our conditions
    $conditions = DB::table('conditions')->select('number', 'field', 'value')->get();

    // here we get all our data
    $imports = DB::table('imports')->get();

    $results = DB::table('results')->get();
    $x = 0;
    $default_value = 0;
    foreach ($imports as $key => $imported) {


        $res = get_object_vars($imported);

        foreach ($conditions as $value) {

            $array = get_object_vars($value);
            $result =  $this->test($columns, $array['field']); // the result of our test function

            if ($result == "ok") {

                if ($res[$array['field']] == $array['value']) {


                    foreach ($results as $value_result) {

                        $res_resultat = get_object_vars($value_result);

                        $test_field = $this->test($columns, $res_resultat['field']);
                        // testing if the condtion numder match with the result number 
                        if (($res_resultat['condition_number'] == $array['number'])) {

                            if (($test_field == 'ok')) {



                                if ($res['id'] != $default_value) {
                                    // here test if the difference between the id and the default value is different from the current id to insert 
                                    if (($res['id'] - $default_value) != $res['id']) {

                                        array_push($current_table2, $results_applied);
                                        array_push($finale_array, $current_table2);

                                        $current_table2 = [];
                                        $results_applied = [];
                                        $default_value = $res['id'];
                                    }
                                    $current_table2 = [$res, $res['id']];
                                }

                                $current_result = [$res_resultat['field'], $res[$res_resultat['field']]];

                                if ($res_resultat['value'] == $res[$res_resultat['field']]) {

                                    $current_result[2] = 'true';
                                    $current_result[3] = $res_resultat['value'];
                                } else {
                                    $current_result[2] = 'false';
                                    $current_result[3] = $res_resultat['value'];
                                }
                                $current_result[4] = $array['number'];
                                array_push($results_applied, $current_result);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $default_value = $res['id'];
    }


    array_push($current_table2, $results_applied);
    array_push($finale_array, $current_table2);

     dd($finale_array);


    return view('Appliedconditions', ['imports' => $finale_array, 'columns' => $columns]);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code. post the code in a code block in your question so we can copy it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are recovering all the data without paging it.
You must paginate the data using the `paginate(#elements_per_page)` directive in your query, where `#elements_per_page` is the number of elements you want to display per page.

For example:

```
$elements = Elements::select('*')->paginate(10);
```

and in your blade view you can retreive pagination links after the closing table tag in this way:          `{{ $elements->links() }}`

Comment: here i get all the imports line without paginating right coz i m filtring them i m testin some coditions and i m rendering informations not from any query  i m collecting infos from the query after testing them then i put them in the array i will render to the view i can paginate the result array ?

Comment: @KhaledAbdelmoumen can you edit your question with your code? I don't understand what you mean and I can't help you